# Getting SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching updates.jenkins.io While Jenkins Plugin Update in Openshift

Tags: jenkins-plugins, openshift-origin

- OS Version: CentOS 7.6
- Openshift OKD 3.11 Multinode Cluster
- Openshift Jenkins Image: openshift/jenkins-2-centos7


  When I go to the Manage Jenkins section to update the Jenkins plugin I got the following **error:java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching updates.jenkins.io found.**
  **error:SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching updates.jenkins.io**


  [image]

```
2020-06-02 21:49:57.178+0000 [id=21]    INFO    hudson.WebAppMain$3#run: Jenkins is fully up and running
2020-06-02 21:49:57.299+0000 [id=47]    INFO    hudson.util.Retrier#start: The attempt #1 to do the action check updates server failed with an allowed exception:
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching updates.jenkins.io found.
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:207)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:98)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:415)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1316)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching updates.jenkins.io found.
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:320)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1332)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1207)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1150)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:177)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1151)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1515)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at hudson.model.DownloadService.loadJSON(DownloadService.java:113)
    at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:185)
    at hudson.PluginManager.checkUpdatesServer(PluginManager.java:1765)
    at hudson.util.Retrier.start(Retrier.java:62)
    at hudson.PluginManager.doCheckUpdatesServer(PluginManager.java:1736)
    at hudson.PluginManager$doCheckUpdatesServer.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at update-center-init$1$2$3.call(update-center-init.groovy:12)
    at update-center-init$1$2$3.call(update-center-init.groovy)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
    at hudson.security.ACL$impersonate.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at update-center-init$1$2.run(update-center-init.groovy:9)
```

Kindly help needed.

Comment: Hi, did you figure this out?